# Calling functions from different Classes in Python

Tags: python, static-methods, inner-classes

I'm relatively new in python and I have the following question, my code looks something like this:

```
class Hkprop:

    def hkprop_f(self):
        hkprop= self.Mkprop().fun2() + self.Fkprop().fun4()
        return hkprop

    class Fkprop:
        def fun1(self):
            #something

        def fun2(self):
            self.fun1()


    class Mkprop:
        def fun3(self):
            #something

        def fun4(self):
            self.fun1() #here I want to call fun1 but I don't know if it is possible or how to do it
```

I know this might be a super basic question, but if someone could help me I would really appreaciate it. I've been looking and came across @staticmethod, but I didn't completely understand. Is there a way of calling the function without using it?

Comment: The name `self` doesn't refer to an instance of `Fkprop` when you're defining 'Mkprop`. I think you are perhaps misunderstanding [nested classes](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/inner-classes-python#WIC).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call fun1, you can do Hkprop.Fkprop.fun1()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is basic but sometimes, even such basic questions takes a little time to figure it out. So, I am assuming that your indentations are correct, and you have nested classes. Here is the solution that I did.... Hope this is helpful to you...
You will need to use the class inheritance methodolody, or simply learn how to instantiate class objects from one class to another as shown below.

When you save this code to a file a run it. You will see that first it will instantiate Hkprop.Mkprop and the call fun4. The next thing, we have done is instantiate Hkprop.Fkprop in func4 to be able to call func1 in FKprop class.

```
    class Hkprop:

    def hkprop_f(self):
        hkprop= self.Mkprop().fun2() + self.Fkprop().fun4()
        return hkprop

    class Fkprop:
        def fun1(self):
            print('I just called this function')

        def fun2(self):
                self.fun1()


    class Mkprop:
        def fun3(self):
             print('this is soemthing')

        def fun4(self):
                fk = Hkprop.Fkprop()
                fk.fun1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mk = Hkprop.Mkprop()
    mk.fun4()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's breakdown your code. You wrote:

```
def fun4(self):
    self.fun1()
```

There are 2 problems here.

1. self represents the instance of the class. Since, Mkprop class has no defintion of fun1() so it cannot access fun1()
2. fun1() function also expects a parameter in Fkprop class

In fun4, if you want to call fun1() then make the following change:

```
def fun4(self):
    Hkprop.Fkprop.fun1(self)
```

Moreover, in python, functions cannot have empty body. Your current code will get the error:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Because the interpreter expects a function body that is indented. To keep the empty functions, change fun1 & fun3 functions like this

```
def fun1():
    pass

def fun3():
    pass
```

pass is a special statement in Python that does nothing. It only works as a dummy statement.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried nested classes before. In your case, it seems like you're calling a nonexistent function from a class. `fun1()` does not exist in class `Mkprop`.

If you want to call `fun1()`, you have to call it from it's respective class, therefore, `Hkprop().Fkprop().fun1()`. It goes something like this: *Parent Class* -> *Sub class* -> *Function*.